# Implementing a function defined by double infinite sums in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, infinite

I want to implement a python function that evaluates a mathematical function (of four variables) defined by a double infinite sum at a particular point.

I've done this by using

```
def myfunction(x):
    value = 0.0
    for m in range(1,100):
      for n in range(1,100):
         value = value + 4.0*(1.0/((n + m)*np.pi**5)) * np.sin(n*x.detach().numpy()[:, 0:1]) * np.sin(m**2 * x.detach().numpy()[:, 1:2]) * np.sin(n*np.pi*x.detach().numpy()[:, 2:3])* np.cos(m*2*x.detach().numpy()[:, 3:4])
    return torch.from_numpy(value)
```

Is there a better (more efficient) way to do this? When I call this function, it runs very slowly (and I'm only summing indices up to 100).

Comment: Store the value of `x.detach().numpy()` at the start of your function. This looks like an expensive function to call. Apart from that, the second and fourth terms can be calculated once for every `m`, but you also recalculate it at every `n`. It will improve performances a bit, but the algorithmic complexity stays the same, so don't expect dramatic improvements. I would try to look for approximations of this functions or alternative formulations.

Comment: You can also factor out `4.0/(np.pi**5)`, and store `x0`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3` before the loop.